# Create Format File with Two Row Delimiters for SQL

Tags: sql-server, bcp, openrowset

I can't seem to find if this is possible, I have a completely flat file that I need to organize to import into SQL server using OPENROWSET.  A sample of the file looks like this:

```
GRP 3 DTL abc DTL def DTL ghi GRP 2 DTL wxy DTL z
```

I wish to import the data so it appears each GRP is one record and each DTL is one record like so:

```
GRP 3
DTL abc
DTL def
DTL ghi
GRP 2
DTL wxy
DTL z
```

While creating the format file it seems like I can only set the format file to take "GRP" or "DTL" as the row delimiter, but not both.  Is it possible to set two row delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the row terminator value to a multiple values.  However, you may be able to make this work without changing the row terminator.  If you set the field terminator to the proper value and add two column definitions in your format file, you should be able to load the data in multiple rows.